# Extract difference between 2 strings with ArrayFormula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, string-comparison

I have a list of initial IDs and a list of resulting IDs  in Google Sheets - I'm looking to have the third "Leftover IDs" column compare the first two columns and return the difference in IDs.

| Initial IDs | Resulting IDs | Leftover IDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NOS202,NOS224 | NOS202,NOS224 |  |
| NOS202,NOS224,NOS227,NOS231,NOS243,NOS318 | NOS202,NOS227,NOS231,NOS243 | NOS224, NOS318 |
| NOS202,NOS224 |  | NOS202,NOS224 |

The formula I have works, but I can't get it to automatically apply to a newly added entry. The error I'm getting with the below formula is "FILTER range must be a single row or a single column"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(EXACT(A2:A,B2:B), "", JOIN(", ", FILTER(SPLIT(A2:A, ", "), NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(B2:B, ", "), SPLIT(A2:A, ", "))))))))
```

Please help! I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(A2:B,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,join(", ",unique(split(join(",",Σ),","),1,1)))))
```

[image]